# Rails 3 ArgumentError: Unknown validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting an error from my model: ArgumentError: Unknown validator: 'datetime_format'

Here is the line that is causing the problem:

```
validates :starttime, :presence => true, :datetime_format => true
```

I have added a class called datetime_format_validator.rb in lib/validators:

```
class DatetimeFormatValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator 
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
     begin 
        dt = DateTime.parse(value)
      rescue
        # add error to 
        object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "date / time invalid")
      end
  end
end
```

Then I updated the application.rb with this line to include files in lib/validators:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/validators/)
```

I have also restarted the rails server, reloaded rails console, etc...

I feel like I may be missing a step... any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Try evaluating const_get('DatetimeFormatValidator') in your rails console and post the result here.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. sorry to respond so late but I didn't see this until now. Here are the results: ?> const_get('DatetimeFormatValidator')
NoMethodError: undefined method `const_get' for main:Object
 from (irb):3